# Best data types for binary variables in Pandas CSV import to decrease memory usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

My original file for training purpose have 25Gb. My machine has 64Gb of RAM. Importing data with default options always ends up in "Memory Error", therefore after reading some posts, I find out that the best option is to define all data types.

For purpose of this question I use a CSV file of: 100.7Mb (it's a mnist data set pulled from https://pjreddie.com/media/files/mnist_train.csv)

When I import it with default options in pandas:

```
keys = ['pix{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, 785)]
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/UI378020/Desktop/mnist_train.csv', header=None, names = ['target'] + keys)
# you can also use directly the data from the internet
#data = pd.read_csv('https://pjreddie.com/media/files/mnist_train.csv',
#                    header=None, names = ['target'] + keys)
```

The default dtypes for pandas is:

```
data.dtypes
```

[image]

How big is it in memory?

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(data)/1000000
```

> 376.800104

If I changed dtypes to np.int8

```
values = [np.int8 for x in range(1, 785)]

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/UI378020/Desktop/mnist_train.csv', header=None, names = ['target'] + keys, 
                   dtype = dict(zip(keys, values)))
```

My memory usage decreases to:

> 47.520104

My question is, what would be even better data type for binary variables to decrease size even more?

Comment: You gotta ask yourself first: is this really necessary? Don't you have 50 MB of free RAM? Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @grooveplex - this is just an example for SO. My real CSV is 25Gb and therefore I need to optimize it as much as I can.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea. Please [edit] your question to make that clearer, because that might drastically change an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the NumPy document [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) the least possible choice for allocating items in the array/list is "int8" dtype of numpy which has the corresponding "int8_t" in C.

For binary lists / list-like objects, "uint8", "int8", "byte" or "bool" types would yield the same size (allocation) for an item which is 1 byte.